# Probability distribution question with drawing letters from a box

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Draw letters with replacement from the following box:
>
> [S  T  A  T I  S  T  I  C  S]
>
> Let $Y$ be the distribution of the number of times the letter 'A' is drawn until you get the letter 'S' 5 times. Find $P(Y = y)$, $E[Y]$ and $Var[Y]$.

I'm having trouble finding $P(Y = y)$. My initial thought was that I could use the Negative Binomial distribution, but I'm not looking for a number of trials until the *rth* success.

Comment: There are two versions of the negative binomial (please see Wikipedia). One counts the number of trials until the $r$-th success, the other counts the number of failures until the $r$-th success. The two versions are of course very closely related. The mean of the second is $r$ less than the mean of the first, and the variances are the same.

Answer (score 1):

$Y$: the count of drawing 'A' until you draw the fifth 'S'

From first principles: The event $\{Y=y\}$ requires you to draw an arrangement of $y$ `A`, $4$ `S`, and some amount of the other letters, and then finally the last `S`.

In essence only draws of A or S are counted, and all draws of `I,T,C` are safely ignored.   They are a distraction; so get rid of them.

What is the probability for drawing an arrangement of $y$ `A` and 4 `S`, then followed by fifth `S`, from `[S,S,S,A]` with replacement?   It is: $~\mathsf P(Y=y)~$.

---

**tl;dr:**

> The distribution **is** that of a *Negative Binomial* for counting successes before the fifth failure with success rate $1/4$.

Comment: why not just say that for {Y=y}, there is a requirement of y A's and 4S's to have been drawn, plus any number of the other letters, then the final S is drawn?

Comment: Yeah, that works too.